# Reading the second or maximum valued mode in R

Tags: r

We can find 'mode' using this function

```
Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}
```

But, this gives least valued mode.
For example, suppose my vector is

```
 find_mode=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,5,5,44,44)
```

And

```
  Mode(find_mode)
  [1] 1
```

I want 44 to be returned. 
44 is the biggest number.

What if I want 3 to be returned?(3rd mode..average: totally 5 modes. And I want third mode)

How can we do it?

Comment: May be you need to `sort` it. i.e. `x <- sort(x, decreasing=TRUE); ux <- unique(x);...`

Comment: Yes its works. This gives the largest number of same mode in the vector

Comment: What about the average valued number of the modes?

Comment: You need to make some changes in the function and another argument in the function call to get the 2nd or 3rd mode

Comment: You could modify the last line of your "Mode" like `tab = tabulate(match(x, ux)); ux[which(tab == max(tab))]`. Then `Mode(find_mode)` would return all the modes and you can `order` the result to get the mode you want.

Comment: @alexis_laz You could post the comment as a solution